# Why does the Lasso only select only $n$ variables if $p \gg n$

Tags: least-squares, linear-regression, regularization

$L_1$ or lasso regularization in regression problems is defined as $$\min||X\beta - y||_2^2 + \lambda ||\beta||_1$$ Multiple resources point out that for $X\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times p}$ if $p \gg n$ lasso only selects $n$ variables and then saturates but they never give a reference or examples (e.g. [elastic net](https://sites.stat.washington.edu/courses/stat527/s13/readings/zouhastie05.pdf)). Also if two columns of $X$ are dependent it's said that lasso selects only one of them and sets all others to zero. This is probably an obvious fact but I can't wrap my head around it.

E.g. if I look at $X = \begin{bmatrix} 0.5 & 0.5\end{bmatrix}$ and $y = 1$ why can't lasso give both of these values equal weight?

Comment: Do you mean only selects $n$ rather than $p$ when $p\gg n$? The point (if I understand your example) with $0.5,0.5$ selecting one rather than two makes no difference (and almost never happens) while with $0.50001,0.5$ selecting just the first will minimise the coefficient term  without affecting the predictions, since you need to multiply by a slightly smaller amount

Comment: you're absolutely right, I meant $n$. I the case where they are independent, at least for $n = 1$ you can always choose the $x_i$ which is largest since $||beta||_1$ will always smallest. But does your comment mean that if they are exactly the same that it is possible for lasso to select both of them with equal weight just unlikely especially in higher dimensions (and depending on the algorithm)?

Comment: If you have two identical columns of $X$ then it depends on the details of the implementation but does not matter and should be rare. If one is a multiple of the other, your Lasso program should choose just the larger one while ridge regression should pick both.   (Something similar happens when you have multiple linearly dependent columns)

Comment: okay thank you, this is not really a question about practicality, it just seemed that everyone suggests that it's impossible but now I see that using "saturates" doesn't suggest that.